# Inverse function as series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, inverse, inverse-function

I have an inverse function of this guy :

$$ y(x)=x^{-1}(y(x))$$
$$ x(y)=
  \frac{1}{4}\Big(-\log[1 - ( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}} y + C_1)] + \log[1 + (  \sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}} y + C_1)] - \frac{2 ( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}} y + C_1)}{(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}} y + C_1)^2-1}\Big)
 $$

Which can be written :
$$ x(y)=
  \frac{1}{4}\Big(\operatorname{arctanh }( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}} y + C_1) - \frac{2 ( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}} y + C_1)}{(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}} y + C_1)^2-1}\Big)
 $$

I'd like very much to have an expression for $y(x)$. I assume the only way is to calculate a serie that fits. But I have no clue how to start the calculation. 
I was thinking about a Fourier series or something with $\frac{e^{k_n x}}{x^p} \; ; \; k_n\in \mathbb{C} \; ;\; n,p\in \mathbb{N}$

Would you have an idea about this ?

Comment: Find $x'$ then invert the ODE and try integrating it. $x'$ is an algebraic function

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible start.

$\begin{array}\\
x(y)
&=\frac{1}{4}\Big(\operatorname{arctanh }( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}} y + C_1) - \frac{2 ( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}} y + C_1)}{(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}} y + C_1)^2-1}\Big)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\Big(atanh ( a y + c) - \frac{2 ( ay + c)}{(ay + c)^2-1}\Big)
\quad a=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}}, c=C_1\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\Big(atanh(z) - \frac{2z}{z^2-1}\Big)
\quad z = ay+c\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\Big(atanh(z) - atanh(w)\Big)
\quad w = \tanh(\frac{2z}{z^2-1})\\
&=\frac{1}{4}atanh\Big(\dfrac{z-w}{1-zw}\Big)\\
\text{so}\\
\tanh(4x(y))
&=\dfrac{z-w}{1-zw}\
\end{array}
$

Not sure 
where to go from here
so I'll stop.